# How come my Preloader barely works in FF and not at all in Chrome?

Tags: jquery

Now the problems might be different for everyone, however in Firefox - the loading finishes and the load div doesn't disappear unless you refresh the browser. In chrome, the load never disappears. I don't have IE so I'm not sure what scary things happen there.

A breakdown of my code:

- **A,B** Preload and set 2 backgrounds
- **C** Load in a container window which will house all content
- Load some content(**D**), and load more content(**E**) inside inside
  content(**D**)
- **F** *Preload* Div on top fades out
- **G** Div with preloaded background(**A**) fades in
- **H** Fade in a DIV which contains container(**C**) and all content(**D**,
  **E**)
- **I** Do some minor initial setup to tables in [functions.js](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/verzia2/js/functions.js)

[Here is what it looks like](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/verzia2/)

And here's the code:
*I put the comment letters on the right-hand side*

```
    var  src1 = 'img/map_bg_1680.jpg'                                                              //A
    , $img1 = $( '<img src="' + src1 + '">' );                                                   //A

    var  src2 = 'img/menu-background.png'                                                          //B
    , $img2 = $( '<img src="' + src2 + '">' );                                                   //B


$img1.bind( 'load', function(){                                                                 //A
    $( '#bgDiv' ).css( 'background-image', 'url( ' + src1 + ')' );                                  //A

        $img2.bind( 'load', function(){                                                         //B

            jQuery('#main-content-fiftyfive').load('index2.html', function() {                     //C
                jQuery( '#viewport-container' ).css( 'background-image', 'url( ' + src2 + ')' );   //A

                $('#right-content').load('partytool.html', function() {                         //D
                    $('#whole-ajax-content-one').load('events.html', function() {                   //E
                        $( '.preloader' ).fadeOut('slow', function() {                              //F
                            $( '#bgDiv' ).fadeIn('slow', function() {                               //G
                                $( '#table-holder' ).fadeIn('slow', function() {                    //H
                                initialConfig();                                                   //I
                        });
                    });
                });
            });     
        });
    });
} );
} );
if( $img1[0].width ){ $img1.trigger( 'load' ); }                                                     //A
if( $img2[0].width ){ $img2.trigger( 'load' ); }                                                     //B
```

Thanks for your help everyone :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only adding the load for `$img2` *after* `$img1` has loaded.  Add them at the same time and have your final callback check to see that both are loaded, e.g.:

```
var img1loaded = false
  , img2loaded = false;

$img1.bind( 'load', function(){
    img1loaded = true;
    finish();
} );

$img2.bind( 'load', function(){
    img2loaded = true;
    finish();
} );

function finish(){
    if( !img1loaded || !img2loaded ){ return; }
    // both are loaded
}
```

Comment: Before I continue, do I keep `if( $img1[0].width ){ $img1.trigger( 'load' ); }` at the end of the code the way it is?

Comment: yes, that is needed in case the image is cached -- the `load` event is never fired in some browsers for cached images

Comment: you dropped your `$img1` and `$img2` definitions :)

Comment: cwolves, this is the second time you've helped me with such a huge issue thank you soooooooo much :))))!!!